# How to trap custom URL scheme from a webview?

Tags: iphone, nsurl, nsurlrequest

In my application, I have a webview which loads up a page that contains both normal links and custom URL schemes, such as myapp://id=1234.

Right now, I am trying to trap the request within this function:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request 
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog(@"NSURLRequest = %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);

}
```

Printing out the url as above gives me this:

```
http://localhost:8888/myapp://id=1234
```

Which is my localhost setup on MAMP with the custom URL appended to the URL.

I had hoped that I could use [request scheme] directly, but in this case now, it simply returns "http".  Is there a way that I can handle custom URL schemes from within my own app?

At this point, I would like to be able to do the following:

1. User is on the webview
2. User taps the custom url link ( myapp://id=1234 )
3. My app handles the custom url and directs the user to another page ( http://www.someotherpage.com/?id=1234 )

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When a URL has a double-slash following the colon, like yours does, the next part is supposed to look like `userinfo@hostname:port` (both `userinfo@` and `:port` can be omitted).  Since `id=1234` does not look like a hostname, the URL parser is not recognizing your URL as an absolute URL.  So the URL parser treats it as a relative URL.

Try changing your URL syntax to either `myapp:id=1234` or `myapp:///id=1234`.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, using the scheme still returns http.  Would it be bad practice to simply use string compares to figure out if the "myapp://" exists, then perform an action?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you shall declare any custom URL scheme as handled by your application.

[Check reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW20)

Comment: Thanks, but isnt this for registering your application to be called by another application?